# Cannot Mount Volume

Tags: linux, debian, operating-systems

I have two internal hard drives.I just installed Debian Lenny in the smaller 80GB.  But when I try to access the other hard drive it shows:

> "Invalid mount option when attempting to mount the volume"

info:

-The 80GB is on dual boot with Windows 7 and Debian Lenny.

-The 500GB secondary hard drive is NTFS filesystem.

-I am a complete newbie and any instructions in a step by step manner would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `/etc/fstab` file?

Answer (score 0):

What command are you running to mount it? For an NTFS volume, it should be something like `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt/data`

Comment: I don't think he's manually trying to mount anything...